# Configuring Hibernate to Mark Fields of a Certain Type as Transient

Tags: hibernate, javafx, tornadofx

Are there any ways to configure Hibernate in this manner? Currently, I must explicitly annotate with `@Transient`. I am using JavaFX, written in Kotlin, and I do not want to persist any property of type `Observable`.

```
@get:Transient
val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty(name)
var name by nameProperty

@get:Transient
val typeProperty = SimpleObjectProperty<ProposalType>(type)
var type by typeProperty

@get:Transient
val salesDateProperty = SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(salesDate)
var salesDate by salesDateProperty

@get:Transient
val commentProperty = SimpleStringProperty(comment)
var comment by commentProperty

@get:Transient
val customerRepository = SimpleObjectProperty<Customer>(customer)

@get:ManyToOne
@get:JoinTable(name = "proposals_customers",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "proposal_fk")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "customer_fk")])
var customer by customerRepository
```

This is the body of one of my classes. Explicitly annotating with `@Transient` works but it can be cumbersome to do this for every class that I need to persist. I have looked through some of Hibernate's documentation and cannot find any configuration where I can define certain types as always Transient.